# Implicit differentiation, its derivative

Tags: implicit-differentiation

I'm unsure how the derivative comes out in the following. I have a parametrization $t'=f(t)$ and a parameter $x(f(t))$ and I'm taking: $\frac{d}{d(f(t))}x(f(t))$. I'm not sure if the derivative would come out as 
$ \frac{df(t)}{dt} \frac{d}{dt}x(t) $ or something else.

Comment: Well, one way to approach this is to use the "fraction" rule
$$
\frac{dx}{df} = \frac{dx}{dt} \frac{dt}{df}
$$
and here $\frac{dt}{df}$ is the inverse of $\frac{df}{dt}$

Comment: That's what I was suspecting. I have another term which is (df/dt)^-1 which I would have wanted the dx/df to cancel out.